# Failed to filter userslist

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple user list application where the admin can do CURD operations on users and filters. I have two components UserList and RoleFilterList. I want to filter the users as per their roles. I successfully fetch filter data from the database whenever I update the `userlist` I can't. I know the reason also that I called `userlist` function inside the `useEffect` whenever the updates by role `userlist` called again I can't get the filter `userlist`. Anyone give me suggestions how to do that. If I remove the dependency users from useEffect wherever I create user I list doesn't update I Have manually refresh the page

### UsersList.jsx

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

const usersList = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/user");
    setUsers(data.users);
};

useEffect(() => {
    usersList();
}, [users]);
```

This is inside the `userlist` component I pass the states as props so I can update them

```
<div className='mb-5 d-flex'>
            <CreateUser />
            <RoleFilterList
                users={users}
                setUsers={setUsers}
            />
        </div>
```

### RoleFilterList.jsx

Here is the role filter component data

```
const [rolesData, setRolesData] = useState([]);
    const [role, setRole] = useState("");

    const handleRoles = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/role`);
        setRolesData(data);
    };

    const handleRoleChange = (event) => {
        setRole(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            `/api/user/role/${role}`
        );

        // console.log(data);

        setUsers(data.users);
    };
```

Comment: What do u mean by this " I successfully fetch filter data from the database whenever I update the userlist I can't. "

Comment: Where are you creating users, trough React from your front end? If so can you past the code for that part?

Comment: @MohammedShahed Please check the `HandleSubmit` function inside the RoleFilterList.jsx you can understand. all the data is coming from my database fetching the exact record I done that How I can I update that data in frontend I the problem

Comment: Hey, @yousoumar I can't understand what you are saying?

Comment: I'm asking how are you creating users.

Comment: @yousoumar through frontend I created a api for createUser and passed the necessary data to create a user. Hey is it possible to pass a function as a prop to another so I can call it whenever I need link if I want to pass the `userList` function to role component or create component

Comment: @dev_Dragon change the useEffect to useEffect(() => {
    usersList();
}, [JSON.stringify(users)]);      and let me know this works

Comment: @LakruwanPathirage No bro It didn't work

Comment: @dev_Dragon if you find the solution, kindly  share the solution with stackoveflow for other developer's reference  as well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok I tried and finally, it worked I removed the `users` dependency from `useEffect`

### UserList.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
    usersList();
}, []);
```

After removing the dependency my code worked as filtering the users based on their roles but there is another problem appeared whenever I create a user that is not updating automatically I solved this problem by passing the `setUsers` method as a prop inside the `CreateUser.tsx` component. And the same `usersList` function I made inside the `CreateUser.tsx` and called it `onSubmit` so wherever I create the list recall the `usersList` function and the list will automatically update. I don't know if this is a good approach or not I am open to suggestions. Please let me know if you better approach.

### CreateUser.tsx

```
const usersList = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/user");
        setUsers(data.users);
    };

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { data } = await axios.post(
            `/api/user`,
            {
                name,
                email,
                role,
                job_preference,
            }
        );
        toast.success("User created successfully");
        usersList();
        resetFields();
    };
```